# Need to Collapse and expand the view on click of button

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create a layout which have initial text view with faded at the end, and than on click of the button, need to expand and collapse the view.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these libraries for expanding text view

https://github.com/bravoborja/ReadMoreTextView
https://github.com/PRNDcompany/ReadMoreTextView

Comment: Thanks for sharing it, any idea on how to make the bottom text as faded

Comment: you can wrap the textview in https://github.com/bosphere/Android-FadingEdgeLayout